# Solr - need the boosting within the sort param

Tags: sorting, solr, liferay-6, solr4, solr-boost

I have a list of docs of solr which would be having 2 fields groupId and assetId. What I want is that the sequence of the list should be all groupId docs together and within that, it should be placed according to the assetId no. This scenario is easily available by modifying sort param.

```
sort=groupId asc,assetId asc
```

But what I want next is, few groupId s should be boosted and shown first.

So my question is how to mention this in sort param, i.e. boosting some of the groupids, compared to others. and each groupId section would be internally ordered based on assetId value.

Through Example:

Data in Solr:

```
GroupId AssetId
 1      A
 2      A
 1      C
 1      B
 3      C
 3      B
 2      C
 3      A
 2      B
```

So

```
sort=groupId asc,assetId asc
```

would result into

```
GroupId AssetId
1       A
1       B
1       C
2       A
2       B
2       C
3       A
3       B
3       C
```

while what I require is groupId 3 and 1 should be boosted to show them before 2. Ordering within each of the groupId 3 , 1, and 2 should be assetId.

```
GroupId AssetId
3       A
3       B
3       C
1       A
1       B
1       C
2       A
2       B
2       C
```

FYI, I am using Solr with Liferay and groupId that needs to be boosted is a dynamic number i.e. it depends on the user currently logged into the liferay. Is it possible to mention boosting in anyway in sort param to specify which value of the sort field are more important?

Comment: Have you tried sorting on just the GroupId or AssetId, and then boosting the value(s) you want?

Comment: @TMBT I tried boosting of the few preferred groupIds in the q param. That didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I had resolved this problem at that time. I used function query concept of Solr in sort param. query({!v="3,1"})

Conceptually, it was like below where 3 and 1 are my groupId's that are required to be above the rest of the groupId. Since we have added two other sort params groupId and assetId, it will basically boost these two groupIds and then within each groupId, it would further sort on assetId.

```
sort=query({!v="groupId:3^10.0 groupId:1^5.0"}) desc, groupId asc,assetId asc
```

Note: I don't remember the exact syntaxes. So please dig into the function query concept and get the exact syntax.